# Error: react-native-permissions: NativeModule.RNPermissions is null. Trying to use react-native-qrcode-scanner

Tags: ios, react-native, qr-code, react-native-permissions

I have tried everything I could find and nothing worked.

What's happening?
I am trying to use the QRCodeScanner Component and this happens, Without it, my app runs fine.

How can it be reproduced?
Make a new expo init Test
then install the basics and add a QR Code Component, add permissions in the ios folder and that's where I'm at.

Build details?
IOS 14.6 QR Code Scanner 1.5.4

Please help me have been stuck at this for hours.

Comment: Seems a problem with linking. Please do `npm install react-native-permissions --save` and then rebuild the project.

Comment: Tried and also doing pod install, same error

Comment: You found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading  `react-native-permissions` to `"react-native-permissions": "3.6.1"`, and rebuild the project .

should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In [`react-native-permissions 3.7.0`](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions/releases/tag/3.7.0) they introduced a new command `react-native setup-ios-permissions` which requires a new way of configuring permissions, only affecting ios.

However I could not get `react-native-qrcode-scanner` to work with it.

Until `react-native-qrcode-scanner` is updated it seems we will have to use `react-native-permissions` version `3.6.1`

In your `package.json` put:

```js
"react-native-permissions": "3.6.1"
```

without the `^` character, so that npm does not accidentally install a newer version.